# If $f(0) = 1$ and $f'(0) = -1$ and $f(x) > 0$ always, what can be said about $f''(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Suppose we have a function $f: [0,\infty) \to R$ so that $f(0) = 1$ and $f'(0) = -1$ and $f(x) > 0$ always, what can be said about $f''(x)$ ?

I think we can't say much about $f''$ because there is no restriction but my answer book says $f''(x) < 0$ for all $x$. I think this is not possible at all, as it would mean $f(x) = 0$ for some $x \in (0,1)$.  Help me.

Also I tried considering $f(x) = \exp(-x)$

Comment: This is certainly false. If $f(x)=1-x$ for $0 \leq x \leq \frac 1 2$ and x for other values all conditions are met and $f''(x)=0$ for $x> \frac 1 2 $. Of course this function is not 'smooth' and it is not even differentaible at 1/2 but there is standard way of modifying it get a smooth function.

Comment: Note for the future: Give all hypotheses. Here it would have been good to say $f$ is twice differentiable on $[0,\infty).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. They must have omitted some important hypothesis or who knows what. Note also that the answer is not $f''(x)>0$ either. While that could be the case (as in the example you gave), you could have a change of convexity/concavity.

For instance, consider $f(x)=\frac1{1+(1+2x)^2}$.

One could add some trigonometric functions to the mix and obtain a function which changes the sign of $f''$ indefinitely. You can say, nevertheless, that is not true that $f''(x)<0$ always. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can pretty much fix any value you want for $f''(0)$.

For instance $g(x)=1-x+\frac a2x^2$ verifies $\begin{cases}g(0)=1\\g'(0)=-1\\g''(0)=a\end{cases}\quad$ for any $a\in\mathbb R$.

By continuity the condition $g(x)>0$ is true in a neighbourhood of $0$, but since $g$ is polynomial it grows to infinity at infinity, we have to make it quickly decreasing in order to build a suitable $f$.

This is possible by multiplying $g$ by $\exp(-\alpha x^4)$ (I choose $x^4$ in order to have no problem with negative numbers, and also such that the second derivative in not impacted by the value of $\alpha$).

Finding a good $\alpha(a)$ so that $f(x)\neq 0$ can be done empirically, but anyway the exponential will always win (just make the coefficient bigger).

For instance $f(x)=(1-x+\frac a2x^2)\exp\left(-\max(1000,a^4)x^4\right)$ is working well.

And $f^{(i)}(0)=g^{(i)}(0)$ for $i=0,1,2$ along with $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

*And this construction can be extended to fix any $n$-th derivative in $0$, provided you take care of the growth of the function far away of $0$ by multiplying by a suitable quickly decreasing exponential.*

Comment: Good answer thanks zwim

Answer (score 1):

I think that, assuming the following, it can be inferred that $f''(x) < 0$ for most, if not all $x \in [0,1)$:

1. The function is continuous in $[0,1)$.
2. $f'(x)<0$ for $[0,1)$.

If so, it can be inferred that also $f''(x)<0$. This way it will remain with a downward slope, as well as a concave, allowing the downward slope to continue indefinitely.

I think continuousness is a fair assumption if you're usually studying that type of functions.

Comment: i think question misses some statements as you say